# Can I restrict an Android user to just be able to pick a Wi-Fi settings?

Tags: wi-fi, settings

I've found a lot of apps that let you lock access to other apps and settings, sadly, they restrict the WHOLE access. I would like to know if there is a way to restrict access to all settings configurations except wi fi connections.